# get all the divs ids on a html page using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

How do I get all the divs ids on a html page using Html Agility Pack. I am trying to get all the ids and put them into a collection.

```
<p>
    <div class='myclass1'>
        <div id='f'>
        </div>  
        <div id="myclass2">
            <div id="my"><div id="h"></div><div id="b"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
```

Code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument(); 
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags=true;
htmlDoc.Load(filePath);    
HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("div");
```

How do I get collection of all divs ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the ID's, you can get a collection of those `id` attribute nodes instead of getting a collection of the `div` element nodes.  For instance:

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();
foreach(XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//div/@id"))
{
    ids.Add(node.InnerText);
}
```

This will skip the `div` elements that don't have an ID, such as the `<div class='myclass1'>` element in your example.

`"//div/@id"` is an XPath string.  XPath is a technology which is vary handy to learn if you deal much with XML, or in this case, HTML via the agility pack library.  XPath is an industry standard which allows you to select matching nodes in an XML document.

- `//` means you want it to select the following node as a child of the current node, or in any of its descendants.  Since the current node is the root node of the document, this will find matching nodes anywhere in the document.
- `div` is an element name we want to match.  So, in this case, we are telling it to find all `div` elements anywhere in the document.
- `/` indicates that you want a child node.  In this case the `id` attribute is a child of the `div` element, so first we say we want the `div` element, then we need the forward slash to say we want one of the `div` element's child nodes.
- `@id` means we want to find all the `id` attributes.  The `@` symbol indicates that it is an attribute name instead of an element name.

Comment: silly question but what notion is //div/@id  what do the forwardslashes mean and the @ this mean

Comment: @Hello-World I added more details to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yo can get the collection of div by passing xpath syntax

Like this

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags=true;

    htmlDoc.Load(filePath);

 foreach(HtmlNode div doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//div"))
 {
///.. code here
 }
```

Comment: so does that look at every node in the html and check if its a div? then in the each i add each id in the loop to my collection?

Comment: @Hello-World //div will get child and all its descendants