# Getting nested Divs using HTML Agility Pack c#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape a webpage (Pub Med) to see how many references appear in specific articles(some articles have references, some don't).  However, the problem i'm having right now is that the divs are all nested and named the same thing so I haven't been able to figure out what code is required to get the elements.

So far i've tried using contains to see if I could just grab a catch all and dig my way into the node from there but that hasn't worked.

```
.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'portlet_title')]");
```

I also have tried copying the XPath but all I would get is null as a result

```
.SelectNodes("//*[@id="disc_col"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/h3/span");
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am no master at Xpath.
And for reference, a page that would fit my criteria is:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=23489346 (right hand side says Cited by * articles).

I've also browsed some other responses however they all seemed to be for results with differently named Divs ( ie [get all the divs ids on a html page using Html Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526554/get-all-the-divs-ids-on-a-html-page-using-html-agility-pack)).  Either I dont understand how to use this correctly, or my problem is different.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Mike! Try use

```
    var titles = website.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='portlet_title']");
```

The errors in your XPaths are: 1. attributes are written just in "[]" with "@" symbol like I wrote; 2. in every XPath node you should write an index e.g. "//div[3]/div[1]/div**[1]**/h3**[1]**/span**[1]**".

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Denis for the response, however using the above still will only get me the "Full Text Links" in a string since that is the first div.  The same problem happens since all the divs are named the same.

Comment: Upon looking into this in much more detail i've realized that the location I need to get seems to be coming into the page as ajax.  It explains why I can only get the Full Text Links part of the source code since everything under it is related to the ajax.  Thank you anyways for your attempt, ill have to find a new way to get this number.